# Angularfire Update nested data

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, angularfire5

I am using angularfire and firebase firestore database to save image data in a database. The saving works 100%.

My data is nested like this :

Images Collection

- galleryId

  - imageId

    - name
    - path
  - imageId

    - name
    - path
- galleryId

  - imageId

    - name
    - path

Sometimes I need to update a specific image object in the database, however, when I try do update an image object / doc I get the following error:

```
Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but images/yuEXbpYWqE4AUfmRCxIu/JvLzEANRFlupuUxYXNii has 3
```

This is the code I user :

```
this.afs.doc('images'+'/'+galleryId+'/'+imageId+'/').update({"name": upload.name,"path": upload.url});
```

I have also tried :

```
this.afs.doc('images').collection(galleryId).doc(imageId).update({"name": upload.name,"path": upload.url});
```

and I have also tried :

```
 this.afs.collection('images'+'/'+galleryId).doc(imageId).update({"name": upload.name,"path": upload.url});
```

and then I get a similar error, just referencing the collection this time :

```
 Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but images/AHcWODRgsespIExQnJae has 2
```

When I try to update other collections in my database it works fine, however, they are only nested 2 levels. It seems that when you have nested 3 levels there are issue.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a document nested directly under another document. You have to structure your nests accordingly: collection - document - collection - document - etc. Firestore paths always start with a collection.

```
this.afs.doc('images/'+galleryId + '/images/' + imageId).update({"name": upload.name,"path": upload.url});
```

I would suggest reading the firestore documentation as this is a fundamental aspect of firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/

Comment: Thx, I will try this and give feedback !

Comment: @Janpan, any luck?

Comment: yes, thanks. It worked perfectly. I got a bit sidetracked because I restructured all my nested data. Thanks for sharing the docs, I understand it much better now, since I was coming from the realtime db :)